# Renaming bands in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, metadata

I've done a layer stack of some Sentinel 2 data in QGIS. Is there a way of renaming the bands in the style menu (in order to reflect what the bands are showing, Red, Green, NIR etc)?

So far they're just called "Band 01" through to "Band 12".